# Linear Algebra - Dimension of Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do I go about finding the dimension of the subspace:
$$S:= \{{ p(x) \in P_4: p(-x)= -p(x)\space \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \}}\space of \space P_4$$
My textbook says $\dim(P_n)=n+1$, but this does not give me the correct answer (the correct answer is 2). All help is appreciated.

Comment: The dimension of $P_n$ _is_ $n+1$. You want the dimension of $S$.Thus, in your example, the dimension of $P_4$ is $5$, and the dimension of $S$, as you found, is $2$.

Comment: you shall understand the question throughly…the set the question is talking about is the set of all fourth degree polynomial that is ODD!

Comment: It might help us, if you say, what $P_n$ actually is. Assuming $P_n$ is the vector space of polynomials of degree equal or less than $n$, then this is the kernel of the linear transformation $p(x) \mapsto p(-x)+p(x)$. What is the dimension of the image (which powers of $x$ will you get)?

Comment: so what is the basis for this vector subspace?

Comment: Pn is polynomials with real coefficients with degree < or = n

Comment: Information like that should be included as part of your question. Why would you assume that everyone knows the notation you are using?

Comment: As far as I know that is what it is always assumed to be.

Comment: Hint (expanded version of Li Chun Min's hint):  Find simple bases -- using just powers of x, first for $P_n$ (just as a warmup), then for $S$.

Comment: @Pelo -- apparently not -- as you can see, you were asked for the meaning by at least one person.

Comment: @Pelo Since you are new here, it would be more productive for your experience if you recognize questions regarding notation as constructive. They clarify your question for others, enabling them to better help you. Plus it is good training, and helps in your own development by explicitly stating what the question refers to.  Rather than your "as far as I know" remark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the set $S$ contains the polynomials $\in P_4$ such that $p(-x) = -p(x)$. So lets start by determining the form of these polynomials. Notice how for a monomial with an  even degree e.g. $x^2$ would return the same value if you were to put $-x$ or $x$ however a monomial with an odd degree e.g. $x^3$ would return minus the value you would get if you  put $-x$ instead of $x$. So the only odd monomials that belong to $P_4$ are $x,x^3$ these then would form your basis as they satisfy the property $p(-x) = -p(x)$ and are linearly independent. Therefore the dimension of the $S$ is $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the linear map
$$
T\colon P_4\to P_4,
\qquad
T(p(x))=p(x)+p(-x)
$$
The matrix $A$ associated to $T$ with respect to the basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ is determined by computing
\begin{align}
T(1)&=2 \\
T(x)&=0 \\
T(x^2)&=2x^2\\
T(x^3)&=0\\
T(x^4)&=2x^4
\end{align}
so the matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has rank $3$ and nullity $2$. Since $S$ is the kernel of $T$, it has dimension $2$ (and is generated by $\{x,x^3\}$).